# Screen abruptly shrinks. What do I do?

Tags: ubuntu, display

I have an ancient LG monitor, don't know the part number. Every so often the picture on the monitor shrinks. By shrink I mean like I have reduced the V-Size of the monitor to a value below 20. I know this is a hardware problem as this can be fixed by shaking the whole monitor a little.

While I would soon get a new monitor anyway, I would like to know why this happens.

Comment: CRT or LCD? they are significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a [failed connection](http://siber-sonic.com/electronics/fracturedSJ.html). Before plugging in your soldering iron, write your will an put on clean underwear - when turned off,  old CRT monitors store very high voltage lethal charges waiting for unsuspecting tinkerers.

Answer (score 0):

If shaking the monitor fixes it, then it's probably a loose part or wire inside.